# Naming of Activity in android

Tags: java, android, naming

I am using someone else's code and they have the following code

```
Intent j = new Intent();
j.setClass(this, ReplaceActivity_.class);
```

but the class they have is "ReplaceActivity". Is there a reason for the "_" after the ReplaceActivity? I am using intelliJ and it gives me a compiler error.

Comment: Probably is a mistake. Try it without the "_" if you have not.

Comment: You need to make sure you have AndroidAnnotations included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for a framework called [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/). The framework reduces boilerplate code by generating bytecode at compile time. The generated Activities have an underscore appended to their names, which is (presumably) why you see this.

Comment: AndroidAnnotations does not generate byte code but only standard and readable java code. You can have more informations here :https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/HowItWorks

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
Intent i = new Intent (presentActivity.this,ReplaceActivity_.class);
StartActivity(i);
```